# Android Marshmallow - Call to a library module(native library) from another library module getting crashed

Tags: android, opencv, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, fatal-error

I have 3 modules in my application named as(For example) **"app"**, **"emp-library"**, **"face-library"**.

**app** - contains only the loading screen and opens the **emp-library** library activity.

**emp-library** - It is the Library module and it contains the basic employee form and camera module to get the employee image and the image will be passed to **face-library** to detect the face.

**face-library** - It is the Library module and it contains the face detection library to detect the face(Native library - own face detection algorithm)

The application is working in the **Lollipop** devices. But when I executes the app in **Marshmallow**, It getting crashed with the below exception.

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xdeadbaad in tid 32696
```

Note: This is the only Error message I got in the logs.

Do I want any specific native library build for the **Marshmallow** devices? Please anybody help me to fix this issue?

**Updated:**

-> As I am not able to find any technical error (up to my knowledge I didn't get any exception in native code) I followed the trial and error method.

-> I have added the **face-library** native call from the **app** module (I shouldn't use this in my case). Now the app **NOT CRASHED**.

-> So, The issue is "**face-library** module call from the **emp-library** module". Both are library modules.

Is there any constraint in **Marshmallow** to call a native library (**face-library**) from the library (**emp-library**) module?

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't need to compile specific version to marshmallow. Because marshmallow works in armeabi-v7 and armeabi, in addition to armV8 which is 64 bits compilation.

Firstly, try to compile your libraries in armv8 version.

Asure that you have the permission in your manifest or if you are asking the permissions (camera for example) in the execution time.

Your error is a generic error, so, you can try native debugging to find which is the library that it is providing the error https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

or you can use a Logger, it works like a c printf.

Here the logger.h

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <strings.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_INFO(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_ERROR(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

#define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

#endif
```

An example in a cpp file:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "logger.h" //include your logger.h
#define LOG_TAG "your_Log_tag"

void Foo::myFunction(char * mystring)
{
 LOGV("Hello foo %s",mystring)
}
```

I hope, this will help you to find the location of the error. If you can be more specific, I can help you to solve the problem.

I usually work, in image processing with OpenCV c++ and Android, and unfortunately these errors are very common.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But When I call from native library from "app" module, the app is not crashed. I have added the logs already. I did get the log it crashed. But nothing valuable(Because, stopped place is the method ending). :(